Can one speak of God the Father being both spirit & body?
And also what objections are there to the position that ALL of Creation is the Body of God the Father? I do not believe that this is the same as pantheism which says the physical universe is god.
The distinction in this position is God the Father is Spirit & Body. Just like Man is both spirit & body. (Man consists of both body & soul.)
A dead body is not a man since there is no spirit. Similarly one can't speak of the Body of the Father as God anymore than a dead cadaver is a man.
Everything that exists both spiritual & physical exist in God. So we think of ALL of Creation as the Body of God the Father.


Can one say that God the Father has Spirit & Body?
What are the objections to the position that ALL of creation is the Body of God the Father?


Hello and welcome to the site! Whose perspective are you after? Most Christians would be quite firm that God the Father does not have a body, but their may be some smaller denominations that teach otherwise (LDS possibly?) For this reason questions need to specify one perspective.

You say this is not pantheism. But, yes, it is. A theological and philosophical position which identifies God with the universe, or regards the universe as a manifestation of God Wikipedia - Pantheism.

This question regards Christianity, that is whether this statement can be considered Truthful or whether it is antithetical to Christianity? As for me personally I am Roman Catholic

This discussion not only invites but requires going deeper into the meaning of words such as pantheism, manifest, & body. My understanding of a pantheist is someone who will dialog with, pray to, even revere a rock or tree, etc. I compare this to a person who finds a toenail clipping & talks to it believing they are dialoging with a person. Anyone dialoging with a rock or tree is as wrong as trying to dialog with a toenail.

If someone defines ‘body’ as a torso with a head, arms & legs then I would strongly support the denial that God the Father has a body.  This is not what I mean by ‘body.’  I think of it more metaphorically, as the body is to a man so all of Creation is to God.  I think this is more in consonance with Catholic Bishop Robert Baron quoting David Burrell’s phase “to be God is to be to-be.” Everything exists in God yet God is not a thing among things. He is being & has Intelligence & Will. He is a person.  Creation is not God in the sense that God’s Spirit is what gives existence to His Body.

The only 'Body' mentioned in scripture in this way is the 'Body of Christ' which is persons not physical objects. That is what is missing from the question. The question is non-scriptural speculation.

@NigelJ The author is describing the false (fundamentalist) version of Panentheism I think.

@MichaelMcMiller Considering that the website allows christian sects that reject the Trinity to submit their answers and questions, this question is a legitimate question for the site even if you weren't an RC christian. Let me know what you think of my answer. Peace be with you

The first problem is that it is an entirely speculative position to take. At least, I can’t think of what scriptures you might use to defend your version of pantheism (or whatever you want to call it).
The second problem is that creation is, well, created - and it is created by God. So you have an order of operations issue to resolve.
The third problem is sin. Whether we look at the angels or at mankind, there’s an awful lot of creation that is sinful and/or corrupted by sin. But God is Holy and without sin. To bring what is profane into the presence of what is Holy has one of several results: either that which is Holy is profaned, or else the profane thing is made Holy, or finally that which is profane is destroyed.
The last of these is generally what happens in scripture when one brings something profane into God’s presence or otherwise sins in His presence. For instance: Aaron’s two sons were burnt up with fire when they offered strange fire to the LORD contrary to what was commanded them.
How then will you reconcile the idea that all of creation is the body of our Holy God despite the fact that so much of creation is sinful - opposing His will and unable to be in His presence?
Fourth: scripture says that God resides in an unapproachable light. This contradicts the idea that all of creation is his body - for we can approach lots of creation, and are ourselves part of creation.

Indeed, creation (God's body?) is under a curse. +1

Thomists (representing the Roman Catholic position) will say yes to "God is in all things", which is as close as to what you said:

Everything that exists both spiritual & physical exist in God.

although NOT the same as "All things are in God".  The source is Summa Theologica Ia.8.1.co, Aquinas's "YES" answer to "Is God in all things?":

I answer that, God is in all things; not, indeed, as part of their essence, nor as an accident, but as an agent is present to that upon which it works. For an agent must be joined to that wherein it acts immediately and touch it by its power; hence it is proved in Phys. vii that the thing moved and the mover must be joined together. Now since God is very being by His own essence, created being must be His proper effect; as to ignite is the proper effect of fire. Now God causes this effect in things not only when they first begin to be, but as long as they are preserved in being; as light is caused in the air by the sun as long as the air remains illuminated. Therefore as long as a thing has being, God must be present to it, according to its mode of being. But being is innermost in each thing and most fundamentally inherent in all things since it is formal in respect of everything found in a thing, as was shown above (I:7:1). Hence it must be that God is in all things, and innermostly.

Christianity teaches that creation is an outflow of God's inner happiness, that creation is ex nihilo (from nothing).  God is NOT nothing, so creation is completely outside God.  Also, God does not need creation, He wants to share that inner happiness with us and He wants to be present to His creation as described above, i.e. as spiritual agent who governs all beings in existence.
The manner of His presence is such that EVEN after creation of physical beings in which God is present in them, those physical beings cannot be seen as God's body.  He did, however, became one of us in Jesus Christ in the Incarnation.  So if you really want to say God has a Body, you can only point to Jesus's body.
Therefore, mainstream Christianity, which excludes LDS, will say "NO" to

Can one say that God the Father has Spirit & Body?


As to

What are the objections to the position that ALL of creation is the Body of God the Father?

we say that's NOT God's way of being present to His creatures. Being an agent that can govern every being in existence is sufficient.  As agent, God can simply "dematerialize" / extinguish any of us at any given moment by removing His sustaining power that keeps any of us in existence.  If the universe is part of His Body, then destroying the universe at the end of time would be like maiming Himself.

I'm eastern orthodox. Here are my thoughts in return, I see multiple issues. And I am certain this has been addressed in the past before by wiser and holier people than me.
First of all, you are speculating. I can see that because there are words you do not yet know, that describe things you are talking about or possibly attempting to describe.
Your primary question seems to be "what objections are there to...?"
Short answer at the bottom :)

The first issue with your train of thought is that God the Father does not have a body or material form. You are right that we are made in God's image, but the reverse is not true. Just because we are an imitation in some sense of God, doesn't really mean that God is fully like us.

We can claim many things, but that does not make it so, your next link in your logic is a fundamental pantheism belief.

Similarly what objections are there to the position that ALL of Creation is the Body of God the Father (Quoted from original question)

This is one of the core principles of the pantheism heresy, even if you say your belief in its entirety is not pantheism ... doesn't really matter because you have already stepped away from what God has revealed to us.

In Eastern Orthodox Christianity, creation is not "part of" God, and the Godhead is still distinct from creation; however, God is "within" all creation, thus the parsing of the word in Eastern and Oriental Orthodox Christianity is "pan-entheism" (God indwells in all things) and not "panen-theism" (All things are part of God but God is more than the sum of all things).
The Eastern Orthodox and Oriental Orthodox Churches have a doctrine called panentheism to describe the relationship between the Uncreated (God, who is omnipotent, eternal, and constant) and His creation that bears surface similarities with the fundamentalist panentheism described above but maintains a critical distinction.
Most specifically, these Churches teach that God is not the "watchmaker God" or mechanical God of philosophy found in Western European Enlightenment. Likewise, they teach that God is not the "stage magician God" who only shows up when performing miracles. Instead, the teaching of both these Churches is that God is not merely necessary to have created the universe, but that His active presence is necessary in some way for every bit of creation, from smallest to greatest, to continue to exist at all. That is, God's energies maintain all things and all beings, even if those beings have explicitly rejected Him. His love of creation is such that he will not withdraw His presence, which would be the ultimate form of slaughter, not merely imposing death but ending existence, altogether. By this token, the entirety of creation is sanctified, and thus no part of creation can be considered innately evil. This does not deny the existence of evil in a fallen universe, only that it is not an innate property of creation.
This Orthodox Christian panentheism is distinct from a fundamentalist panentheism in that it maintains an ontological gulf or distance between the created and the Uncreated
Source: OrthodoxWiki on Panentheism (Italic "fundamentalist" added by me for clarity of reading.)


Now that we've identified the two basic concepts of your position. Here are the objections to your fundamental positions.
All of creation is the body of God the Father, is false.

God the Father never became the likeness of any material form nor was He ever incarnate. (Father Alexander, Short Exposition of Orthodox Doctrine)


God the Father, Who is without beginning, indescribable, incomprehensible, Who is beyond every created essence, Whose essence is known only to Himself, to His Son and the Holy Spirit; as it says in the Holy Scriptures, upon Him even the Seraphim dare not gaze. (Father Alexander, Short Exposition of Orthodox Doctrine)


"No man hath seen God at any time; the Only-begotten Son, Who is in the bosom of the Father, He hath declared Him," (John 1:18)


"Not that any man hath seen the Father, save He Who is of God, He hath seen the Father" (John 6:46).


In addition, Acts Four, Five and Six of the Seventh Ecumenical Council state that the Holy Trinity cannot be portrayed iconographically since He (God the Father) is without from and invisible. (God the Father is not depicted in holy icons.)

Also, we should consider that God do not need to make us. It would have not caused God any privation if he had not created us or this universe. He need not have created us, but did so anyways.
The next thing is of course that there will be a "new heaven" and "new earth" which of course would be deeply distressing if those things were somehow God the Father's body...

New heavens and a new earth wherein dwelleth righteousness (2 Peter 3:13)

God is unchanging and eternal by nature and in essence. So the "body of God" as you put it cannot be the heavens and earth (the universe) as those created material things are going to be remade.
These are the objections that come to my mind.

Short Answer: No, you cannot speak of God the Father as "Spirit and Body", God the Father has no material form. To claim otherwise is contrary to scripture and the teachings of the Orthodox Church. Your version seems to be a fundamentalist version of Panentheism.
